# How to remove white space that cannot be selected with developer tools

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have white space on my website that I cannot identify with developer tools and would like to remove:

[image]

I have created a [Tailwind Play example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Mx7UGoSKWL).
How to remove the white space between the cover image and the article box?

Comment: your GIF image is not showing can you please update ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `header` element. You gave it a class of `min-h-screen` with gives `min-height: 100vh;` on that element.

You also apply `top-[-3.75rem]` to the element which gives `top: -3.75rem`. Removing that should remove the extra space.

```
<header class="flex w-full relative top-[-3.75rem] mx-auto bg-black min-h-screen items-center justify-center">
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for the investigation and information. I added this as the navbar is transparent as long as I don't scroll down and otherwise there would be a white space instead of the cover image visible.

Comment: I've updated the [`playground`](https://play.tailwindcss.com/5xysLmjtUm) to have a possible fix. I wrapped the header's content with another element and added the top and absolute styles to it. That way, the header doesn't shift back and cause the white space to show

Comment: If you don't want the header's black background to show, you can increase the height of the element I used to wrap with h-[calc(100vh+3.75rem)] i.e. screen height + the top distance. [`playground`](https://play.tailwindcss.com/O7dvuWmbmS)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick :)